# Does Baasbox encrypt communication?

Tags: baasbox

I am moving all my stuff from Parse.com for many reasons. Parse had a point-to-point encryption between server and client.

Does anyone know if Baasbox has the same or the passwords are travelling in plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.

Just start your server so:

```
./start -Dhttps.port=9443
```